# Live video stream format with metadata for dumping on Debian

Tags: php, linux, video, metadata, live-streaming

I have a little trouble.
I need to dump live video stream and split it into pieces. I can choose specification and format of this stream (in which I will receive it). The other side will send stream in the format that i'll choose.
I need to receive metadata that contains date and time for every second of this video stream.
Then I need to split this stream according to date and time, and save pieces to hard drive.
OS is Debian. PHP included.

Could someone help me to choose proper format of this live video stream and the best way that I can split it on my side? Please, ask questions, if you want.

Also if you can make proposal how I can identify any frame and bind it to time in which it was shooted, please, answer me.